# How determinate if two list of Coordinate are opposing

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems

There are two lists of Coordinates that represent the car path. I must determinate if these lists are opposed ( the direction of car ara opposed).
Anyone can suggest me one method?

Comment: Coordinates are just points, with no sense of direction. You need direction vectors in order to determine relative directions.

Comment: @twalber I obtain this list of coordinate from a web Service but I know that this web service don't have this information!